# File Permission does not change on android device

Tags: java, android, file, android-permissions

I have android app which has  a file which was created with world readable permission using the following api of java class -

```
File.setReadable(true, false);
```

Now I want to change the permission of file and make it readable to owner only. We tried to execute below code

```
File.setReadable(true, true);
```

The api returns true. 
But the permission of file is not changing.

File is still world readable.

Note: File is created in app sandbox.
Anyone has any input on this? How to get it done

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14054278/4782930) is what u need?

Comment: In my case file and directory already exist. I need to change permission of existing file. The link given is for new file

Answer (score 0):

One solution that worked for me is to remove the read permissions completely and then setting it again for owner only:

```
file.setReadable(false, false);
file.setReadable(true, true);
```

Starting from a file with `r--r--r--`, this gets you to `r--------`.